# Is "something appetite" correct as a noun?

Tags: meaning

Trying to find a name for a restaurant using *appetite* word. As my native language is not English, Do combinations such "Apple Appetite", "Pizza Appetite" make sense?

Comment: I think you mean 'Would they sound acceptable?' Try searching the internet for examples of restaurant names using the word 'Appetite' and see how many people think it's a good choice.

Comment: I tried but didn't find something similar. I thought may be it is not correct.

Comment: You can make up any name you like and nobody will come and arrest you (as long as it's not rude or treasonable). But a name like 'Apple Appetite' probably wouldn't attract many customers either. 'Pizza Delight' or 'Mad for Apples' might work better.

Comment: There are many restaurants just called Appetite :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about naming.

Comment: Combine them, Appletite.

Comment: I don't know about all of you, but I would visit a restaurant called "Apple Appetite". I'm fond of alliteration and would have a general curiosity about what was served at "Apple Appetite"; maybe a trendy raw food and juice bar?

Comment: Consider the area where you will open your restaurant; is it residential, urban, suburb, countryside etc. Are the residents mainly native or non-native speakers?  The name of your restaurant should be easily comprehensible. If you call it "Apple Appetite", people might initially assume it specializes in apple-type snacks or desserts, until it builds a name and reputation for itself. I like the sound of that name, but there should be some connection with the menu served (obviously).

Answer (score 2):

"Apple Appetite" isn't how a native speaker would put it. They/I would say any of the following:

```
I have an appetite for apples
I am hungry for apples
I want an apple
```

Thus, a straight substitute in context might be:

```
Appetite for Apples
Hungry for Apples?
Want Apples?
```

All of which would be reasonable restaurant names in my opinion (British English), assuming your resturant serves only or mainly apples.

Comment: Restaurant names and British English - As long as _the Fat Duck_ is a good name for a restaurant that does _not_ mainly have overweight poultry on the menu...

Comment: hmm, the Fat Duck is in the tradition of Pub Names, which are normally a completely random (= distinctive) noun, including anything from *The Kings Head* to *The Bunch of Carrots* ([source for the latter](http://www.buzzfeed.com/lukelewis/the-23-weirdest-pub-names-in-britain))

Comment: @tehwalrus: actually, pub names aren't random. They come from sign names - a pub that had a mermaid on its sign would come to be called The Mermaid, while a pub that had a green elephant on its sign would be called The Green Elephant. Thus, you wouldn't find a pub called "The Yard" or "The Promotion" — or "The Appetite" — because you can't draw those on a sign.

Comment: The _The Commercial_ is a common pub-name in Yorkshire, where I now live.

Answer (score 0):

Consider "The [Toothsome](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/toothsome) Apple" and "Bon Appletreat!" (from French *bon appétit!*) for the name of your restaurant.

Comment: The second would make a catchy name for either a snack bar or patisserie specialising (maybe) in strudels. I like it!

Answer (score 0):

How about "Apple-Tite" for the first one?

Comment: Better without the hyphen, Appletite.

Comment: *Bon Appletart* for a cake shop.

Answer (score -2):

Your word formations with "appetite" make no sense.

Comment: Do you mind telling us *Why* the word formations do not make sense?

Comment: See a dictionary. eg OALD.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is absolutely ignorant. No dictionary, neither OALD nor any else, will tell me if a word formation that is intend to be a name for a restaurant is valid or not. If I want to call it "Apple Appetite" it doesn't matter if this would be grammatically or semantically fine in an English text.